# what's wrong with my JSpinner.DateEditor?

Tags: java, swing, date, simpledateformat, jspinner

i am creating my JSpinner. If i don't use "dateSpinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(dateSpinner, "DD:MM:YYYY"));", the GUI works well, displaying the date and time correctly, e.g, 12-2-13 11:39. But if i use it, the date gets wrong, showing 44/02/2012. What's the problem? Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

```
private JPanel getTimePanel() {
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Calendar"));

        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        Date initialDate = cal.getTime();
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -50);
        Date earliestDate = cal.getTime();
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 100);
        Date latestDate = cal.getTime();

        SpinnerDateModel dateModel = new SpinnerDateModel(initialDate,
                                                          earliestDate,
                                                          latestDate,
                                                          Calendar.DATE);
        JSpinner dateSpinner = new JSpinner(dateModel);
        //dateSpinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(dateSpinner, "DD:MM:YYYY"));
        // Add GUI components
        centerPanel.add(dateSpinner);

        return centerPanel;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that your format String is incorrect.  It should follow the conventions of the SimpleDateFormat: `"dd:MM:yyyy"`